# Which classifier should i pick among knn,dt,rf?

Tags: classification, data-science, data-mining

i am curious about something. Lets say i have knn, dt, rf for classification and obtained some results. Lets say when i investigate the test set all of the 3 algorithm give me the same accuracies. According to these which criterias should i investigate to choose the most suitable ?

Answer (score 0):

There's more to classification than just accuracy.
It might be interesting to look at confusion matrices for the three methods, and see which model gives the best results for your use-case.

Example:
If you have a dataset with 99% of elements belonging to class A and 1% to class B, then the three methods will all achieve 99% accuracy by only ever predicting an element to belong to class A. However, these models have no use to you and your problem.

Comment: Accuracy is deriven from confusion matrix. What can i also obtain from that matrix ?

Comment: Sensitivity, specifity, precision, ... for example.
Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity